# Oracle SQL to append character based on count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to write a Oracle SQL Select query to dynamically append a certain character based on the value in a column.

```
For Eg -
COLUMN1
1
2
3
Then result should be,
COLUMN1 DERIVED_COLUMN
1          @
2          @@
3          @@@
```

Right now, I tried with case and decode but they are not dynamic.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, DECODE(COLUMN1, 1, '@', 2, @@, .....) FROM MY_TABLE
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RPAD`:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN1,
    RPAD('@', COLUMN1, '@') AS DERIVED_COLUMN
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you want instead to repeat *words*, then we can use `RPAD` with a multiple which is the number of characters in the word to repeat, e.g.

```
SELECT
    COLUMN1,
    RPAD('test;', COLUMN1*5, 'test;') AS DERIVED_COLUMN
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

### Demo

Comment: RPAD appends only one character ? Is there any way to append more than one character ? Like column value is 1 then TEST;. If 2 then TEST;TEST;